# What is the value of $c$ so that $f$ becomes continuous over the whole domain?

Tags: limits, continuity

Let $f$ be defined as follows
\begin{align*}
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{4x^{2} - 39x + 27}{x - 9} &\text{if}\quad x\neq 9,\\
c &\text{if}\quad x = 9
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

I can't really grasp how to choose the constant $c$ so that the $f(x)$ becomes continuous.

Could someone help me understand this?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Could you please tell us what you have tried so far? What about checking if $x = 9$ is a root of $4x^{2} - 39x + 27$?

Comment: @APCorreia I haven't tried anything to be honest because I haven't actually done anything similar in my book. So I don't know how to go about these questions.

Comment: Try to apply the hint I have given you.

Comment: @APCorreia I will, thank you, I'll be back with more questions if I have them!

Comment: You are welcome !

Comment: @APCorreia So I used the quadratic formula and came to the answers x1=9, x2=3/4 , What to do with this information?

Comment: Since $4x^{2} - 39x + 27 = (x-9)(4x-3)$, you can cancel the factor $x - 9$ in order to obtain
$$\lim_{x\to 9;x\neq 9}\frac{4x^2 - 39x + 27}{x - 9} = \lim_{x\to 9;x\neq 9}\frac{(x-9)(4x-3)}{x - 9} = \lim_{x\to 9;x\neq 9}(4x-3) = 33$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: @APCorreia okay now I understand it. Thank you for helping me through it, you were really helpful. I wont forget this to other questions like these!

Comment: I am glad to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:

You have to show the fraction has a limit when $x\to 9$, which means $x-9$  is a factor of $4x^2-39x+27$. Hence perform the Euclidean division  by $x-9$.